# What is fieldIndex about in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I read JOOQ API documentation about following APIs, but still couldn't understand what is fieldIndex about.

```
fetchAny(int fieldIndex, java.lang.Class<? extends T> type)
```

For example, in the following code I already knows which column to select, why do we need filedIndex of 0? What does 0 mean?

```
String name = getDslContext().select(TESTB.STU_NAME)
            .from(TESTB)
            .where(TESTB.ID.eq(studentId))
            .fetchAny(0, String.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ mostly operates on [`Record`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html) types. For instance, when you create the following query:

```
.select(TESTB.STU_NAME)
.from(TESTB)
.where(TESTB.ID.eq(studentId));
```

You're really operating on a [`ResultQuery<Record1<String>>`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html). By calling [`fetchAny(0, String.class)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchAny-int-java.lang.Class-) on that type, you're telling jOOQ that you want to fetch any record, and from that record, you want to get only the value at index `0`, converted to `String`.

This may feel like repeating the same information twice (using `TESTB.STU_NAME`, and fetching the column at index `0`). This is because fetchign a single value is quite a special case in the jOOQ API. Unfortunately, the [`ResultQuery` API](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html) doesn't really "know" that you're selecting only one column even if that type information is present via generics.

One alternative would be to use [`DSLContext.fetchValue(ResultQuery)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchValue-org.jooq.ResultQuery-):

```
String name = getDslContext().fetchValue(
    DSL.select(TESTB.STU_NAME)
       .from(TESTB)
       .where(TESTB.ID.eq(studentId))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for nice and clean answer. You also mentioned the alternative solution. Which is one is proffered way? Does the alternative solution guarantee to return almost one record? I need to get only one record. By the way do you recommend a good JOOk book for a beginner?

Comment: @user3123690: Sorry for the delay. There is no preferred way. But yes, the "alternative solution" `DSLContext.fetchValue()` will guarantee to return at most one value. Otherwise, an exception is thrown as indicated in the [linked Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchValue-org.jooq.ResultQuery-). There is a [free jOOQ course at the JCG Academy](http://academy.javacodegeeks.com/course/type-safe-database-querying-with-jooq/).